# Shiny app docker container not loading in browser

Tags: docker, shiny, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I containerised a shiny app and attempted to deploy it on GCP using Kubernetes but each time I obtain the external IP address and load it in the browser, I get the "this site cannot be reached connection refused" error. So I have attempted to run the container on my localhost to troubleshoot and now I get the "127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error. I searched tirelessly online for a solution but nothing seems to work for me. Plus none of the solutions on are for a shiny app docker container. Many of the fixes mention the port but I am still stuck. I have xampp installed on my mac by the way. Is it possible that xampp and my docker container are attempting to share the same port or is there a problem with my Docker file code? Pardon me but I am new to containers and have only been following the documentation procedure up till now. Below is my Docker file code:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Install R version 3.5.1
FROM r-base:3.5.1

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
sudo \
gdebi-core \
pandoc \
pandoc-citeproc \
libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
libcairo2-dev/unstable \
libxt-dev \
libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer (latest version)
RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os- 
build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os- 
build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && 
\
gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

# Install R packages that are required
# TODO: add further package if you need!
RUN R -e 

"install.packages(c('shiny','shinyjs','tools','foreign','XLConnect'), 
repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

I would appreciate it if someone could assist me.

Comment: There [is](https://store.docker.com/community/images/quantumobject/docker-shiny) a working Docker image for shiny why you create your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to first create a Rprofile.site file and place it in the same directory as the dockerfile and shinyapp. Then I created my own base image with all the necessary libraries for the app and called it from my dockerfile. Here is the final code:

**Rprofile.site**

```
local({
options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0")
})
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM bimage_rpackages

# Copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/shinyapp
COPY app/shinyapp /root/shinyapp

COPY app/Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 3838
EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/shinyapp')"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need shiny-server.

add

```
app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, host ="0.0.0.0", port = 80, launch.browser = FALSE)
```

to your R script and

```
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["R", "-e", "library(shiny); source('/root/pathToYourScript/script.R')"]
```

to your Dockerfile.

Comment: I included the above as you mentioned; removed the all commands that run shiny server and the config files but I still cannot access the shiny app from my container over the browser. I still get the "this site cannot be reached connection refused" error. I changed the port to 3838 in both my shiny app and exposed at 3838 on my docker file but still not working (i thought xampp using port 80 was interfering with the container).

Comment: Here is a detailed guide: https://www.shinyproxy.io/deploying-apps/ just modify it to your needs (and ignore the shinyproxy details).

Comment: I solved the problem - there were some outdated and missing libraries for the shinyapp. It is working both on my local computer and the on google cloud. Thanks!