# Shiny app not showing up after building Docker image and specifying port

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile

I'm currently trying to build a large Docker image and run a shiny application off of it so I can eventually deploy it to a Unix server. The image builds successfully; however, when I go to run the image, the app runs and totally ignores the specified port.

What's even more strange is I first built a small test app, and the instructions from this SO post ([Shiny app docker container not loading in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878149/shiny-app-docker-container-not-loading-in-browser)) worked. I copied the same style I used in the test app into the other Shiny application and now it is not working.

The structure of my Docker image follows a similar structure to what ShinyProxy used on their Github page: https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-template:

```
|-- Dockerfile
|-- Rprofile.site
|-- app_stuff
    |-- app.R
    |-- accessory files called from app.R...
```

My **Dockerfile** is below:

```
# Install R version 3.5.1
FROM r-base:3.5.1

# system libraries of general use - I don't know if these are right ????
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    default-jdk \
    libbz2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    gfortran \
    liblzma-dev \
    libpcre3-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    xorg-dev \
    sudo \  
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libxml2-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes');"
RUN R -e "library(remotes); \
remotes::install_version('shiny', version='1.1.0', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('tidyverse', version='1.2.1', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('ggiraph', version='0.6.0', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('plotly', version='4.8.0', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('CausalImpact', version='1.2.3', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('reshape2', version='1.4.3', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('bsts', version='0.8.0', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('xts', version='0.10-2', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('BoomSpikeSlab', version='1.0.0', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('Boom', version='0.8', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('MASS', version='7.3-50', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('dygraphs', version='1.1.1.4', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('prophet', version='0.4', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('rlang', version='0.3.3', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('Rcpp', version='1.0.1', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('zoo', version='1.8-1', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('RJDBC', version='0.2-7.1', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('rJava', version='0.9-10', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('shinyjs', version='1.0', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('DT', version='0.5', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'); \
remotes::install_version('shinyBS', version='0.61', repos='https://cran.r-project.org/');"

# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/app_stuff
COPY app_stuff /root/app_stuff

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app_stuff')"]
```

My **Rprofile.site** is:

```
local({
   options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0")
})
```

After building the file using the command

```
docker build -t price_opt .
```

and then running the image

```
docker run -it -p 3838:3838 price_opt
```

I expected to see the shiny app print out: `Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3838`, but instead it prints out:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6688
```

Which I'm unable to find on my local machine.

Again, the weirdest thing is this type of setup worked for a smaller shiny app. When I ran that `docker run` command from above on the smaller app, the app was available under localhost:3838.

Any thoughts on why this is happening? My last thing is it looks like this user on the Shiny Proxy site had a similar issue (https://support.openanalytics.eu/t/shiny-app-listening-on-wrong-host/957). His issue is a typo of sorts, but it does seem to be acting the same way here where the Shiny app is totally ignoring the supplied port number in both Rprofile.site and the `docker run` command.

### EDIT - Solution

Thanks to user @Wil, by changing the last line of the Dockerfile to `CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app_stuff', host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]`, the app was able to start up normally on localhost:3838.

Comment: Try specifying the port in `runApp()` , i.e.`CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app_stuff',options = list(port = '3838'))"]`

Comment: This is what did it @Wil, I changed the last line of the Dockerfile to `CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app_stuff', host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]` and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! some explanation about this issue ? last week rprofile did the job but this time seems all is broken ? why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Port 3838 is the default port for Shiny Server, but `runApp()` chooses an available port. It appears R is not picking up your `Rprofile.site`, so I would just specify the port in your call to `runApp()`:

```sh
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app_stuff',options = list(port = '3838'))"]
```